# multilevel regression and poststratification mrp

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis, survey, stratification

I have some survey data. I want to calculate a regression with a stratified sample of this data. Because of the stratification, the sample size gets really small. Due to this, the standard error of the regression and the confidence intervals get quite large. I read about the MrP to solve this problem.

Here is an example:

```
library(TeachingSampling)
library(lme4)
library(dplyr)

glimpse(Lucy)

Observations: 2,396
Variables: 8
$ ID        <fct> AB001, AB002, AB003, AB004, AB005, AB006, AB007, AB008, AB009, AB010, AB011, AB012, AB013, AB014, A...
$ Ubication <fct> c1k1, c1k2, c1k3, c1k4, c1k5, c1k6, c1k7, c1k8, c1k9, c1k10, c1k11, c1k12, c1k13, c1k14, c1k15, c1k...
$ Level     <fct> Small, Small, Small, Small, Small, Small, Small, Small, Small, Small, Small, Small, Small, Small, S...
$ Zone      <fct> A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, ...
$ Income    <int> 281, 329, 405, 360, 391, 296, 490, 473, 350, 361, 374, 419, 402, 330, 411, 340, 311, 342, 342, 404,...
$ Employees <int> 41, 19, 68, 89, 91, 89, 22, 57, 84, 25, 34, 20, 19, 23, 36, 12, 34, 40, 60, 47, 49, 42, 94, 56, 49,...
$ Taxes     <dbl> 3.0, 4.0, 7.0, 5.0, 7.0, 3.0, 10.5, 10.0, 5.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 7.0, 4.0, 7.0, 5.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.0, 7....
$ SPAM      <fct> no, yes, no, no, yes, no, yes, yes, yes, no, yes, no, yes, yes, no, no, no, yes, yes, no, yes, yes,...
```

The data set contains some financial variables of 2396 industrial companies. Let´s say I want to know about the earnings (Income) predicted by/of a  subset that is located in `Zone` A, Small `Level` and no `SPAM`. As you can see, the size of that subgroup is just 36.

```
Lucy %>%
  filter(Level == "Small" & Zone == "A" & SPAM == "no") %>%
  nrow()
[1] 38
```

MrP says to calculate a multilevel regression first.

```
lucy_m = lmer(Income ~ (1 | Level) + (1 | Zone) + (1 | SPAM), data = Lucy)

summary(lucy_m)


Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: Income ~ (1 | Level) + (1 | Zone) + (1 | SPAM)
   Data: Lucy

REML criterion at convergence: 29996.8

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.1649 -0.7734 -0.0783  0.7005  9.8109 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Zone     (Intercept)   2589    50.88  
 Level    (Intercept) 211065   459.42  
 SPAM     (Intercept)      0     0.00  
 Residual              15835   125.84  
Number of obs: 2396, groups:  Zone, 5; Level, 3; SPAM, 2

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)    735.7      266.3   2.763
convergence code: 0
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
```

Now, there is a point I can´t get any further. I have to poststratify by taking the mean of each group's prediction weighted by their frequency in the whole sample (i.e. the total amount of Level, Zone, SPAM).  Any idea how to do this?

Comment: The "poststratification" of MRP is a technique to estimate a statistic (Income here) on a population different from the one in your dataset. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilevel_regression_with_poststratification or https://www.r-bloggers.com/gelmans-mrp-in-r-what-is-this-all-about/. What population do you want to predict on, and is it different from the dataset? If you just want to predict from your model, `Lucy$prediction <- predict(lucy_m)`.